# Add links to datagridview

Tags: vb.net

i hava a datagridwview with a datagridviewlinkcolumn and a split array with the links. How can I add this links from the array to the datagridviewlinkcolumn?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you can use the add function of your datagrid to add it.

If you have only one column in your datagrid, then it would look like this

```
For each strLink as string in strLinks 'strLinks if your array
    gridLinks.Rows.Add(strLink)   
Next
```

However, I would use strongly type object and define your column with a DataPropertyName and add a datasource to your datagrid. That way you could have more than one column and rearrange without the need to change the code.

Hope that helps.